# Confused about ISSN number in Researchgate

Tags: publications, journals

We've recently published a paper in [Physical Review D](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.056028) and then I just wanted to add this to my Researchgate profile. And when I was filling the journal's name, I got three options:

[image]

I'm a little bit confused since the ISSN of PRD is 2470-0010 according to [PRD itself](https://journals.aps.org/prd/about).

Can anyone tell what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happened is that the name of Physical Review D has been slightly tweaked over the years, and a [new journal title means a new ISSN](https://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/assignment-rules/issn-the-major-principles/). Often university library records are helpful to figure out these changes. As per https://library.usask.ca/ejournals/publisher.php?publisher=American+Physical+Society+Journals the journal was called

1. "Physical Review D: Particles and Fields" from vol. 1 (1970) to vol. 68 (2003), with ISSN 0556-2821 and E-ISSN 1089-4918
2. "Physical Review D: Particles, Fields, Gravitation, and Cosmology" from vol. 69 (2004) to vol. 92 (2015), with ISSN 1550-7998 and E-ISSN 1550-2368
3. "Physical Review D" from vol. 93 (2016) to present, with ISSN 2470-0010 and E-ISSN 2470-0029.

(These ISSNs can also be found at the [ISSN Portal](https://portal.issn.org/api/search?search%5B%5D=MUST=default=physical+review+d&search_id=14245337#) but without the information on when a given name change happened.)
The most recent numbers match what you see on PRD's website. These are correct, but there's no guarantee that numbers showing up on websites like ReseatchGate are.

Anyway, I suggest that you sit back and wait for maybe a week before trying to add the article manually. Usually ResearchGate indexes new papers in APS journals automatically, and will suggest adding new articles it finds. That way you don't need to worry about figuring out which of these incorrect ISSN numbers ResearchGate believes PRD papers should be assigned.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Just a quick note: I've already added the article manually, should I delete it?

Comment: I'd probably leave it there. If it becomes an issue later, where RG thinks you have two different papers maybe you could think about deleting the manually added version. (Or maybe there's some merging functionality.) Anyway, I think very few readers will care about the ISSN details. We know PRD is PRD.